# Set up a crontab to automatically start a FiveM server on a screen

Tags: linux, cron, fivem

I am trying to set up an automated crontab to start my FiveM servers usingtxAdmin. This is what I currently have:

```
@reboot screen +set serverProfile FWRP_Server1 /[path]/run.sh
@reboot screen +set serverProfile FWRP_Training +set txAdminPort 40121 /[path]/run.sh
@reboot screen +set serverProfile FWRP_FivePD +set txAdminPort 40122 /[path]/run.sh
```

It's not starting the screens. I think my problem is twofold. First I'm not sure where to put the set parameters. The normal spot for this one is directly after the /run.sh if I were to do it manually but that didn't work. Second, do I need to detach from the screen somehow for the first line before doing the next server since you have to so that when running it manually?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly i have writen a bash like this

```
screen -dmS FIVEM ../run.sh
```

so, i think you can just written a bash with all your command on it and launch this script with crontab. Do you have trying this ?

With your code that doing this

```
screen -dmS FWRP_Server1 +set serverProfile FWRP_Server1 /[path]/run.sh
screen -dmS FWRP_Training +set serverProfile FWRP_Training +set txAdminPort 40121 /[path]/run.sh
screen -dmS FWRP_FivePD +set serverProfile FWRP_FivePD +set txAdminPort 40122 /[path]/run.sh
```

The screen command with -dmS is for launch a detached screen with the command. To reattach the screen just doing this :

```
screen -r FWRP_Training
screen -r FWRP_FivePD
screen -r FWRP_Server1
```

**EDIT 1**

The batch files is like this `/your/path/launch_fivem.sh`

is content

```
screen -dmS FWRP_Server1 +set serverProfile FWRP_Server1 /[path]/run.sh
screen -dmS FWRP_Training +set serverProfile FWRP_Training +set txAdminPort 40121 /[path]/run.sh
screen -dmS FWRP_FivePD +set serverProfile FWRP_FivePD +set txAdminPort 40122 /[path]/run.sh
```

and on crontab, you add

```
@reboot /your/path/launch_fivem.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have never written a bash script or called a script in cron. Would you be able to point me in the right direction for that? I have very little linux experience. haha

Comment: i have edit my post for the help ;)

Comment: Alright I have added what you suggested and it is still not starting the servers

Here is what the crontab looks like:
```
@reboot /root/all_servers/fivem_start.sh
```
And here is my fivem_start.sh file:
```
screen -dmS FWRP_Server1 +set serverProfile FWRP_Server1 /root/all_servers/server1/run.sh
screen -dmS FWRP_Training +set serverProfile FWRP_Training +set txAdminPort 40121 /root/all_servers/training/run.sh
screen -dmS FWRP_FivePD +set serverProfile FWRP_FivePD +set txAdminPort 40122 /root/all_servers/fivepd/run.sh
```
Am I missing anything in the batch file?

Comment: have you try to launch the batch manualy ?

Comment: Yes, at first there was a permissions issue but I fixed that. Now when I run it, my debug console print works but no screens are created